# How to find the difference between 2 IEnumerable objects

Tags: c#, .net

I have 2 list of guids as:

```
IEnumerable<dynamic> userids = null;
IEnumerable<dynamic> lsCheckedUsers = null;
```

The userids and lsCheckedUsers list are populated from a SQL database using dapper.

I now wish to find all userids that are not in lsCheckedUsers.

I have tried the following

```
var userdifference = userids.Where(i => !lsCheckedUsers.Contains(lsCheckedUsers));
var userdifference = userids.Except(lsCheckedUsers);
```

None of the above actual returns the difference between the 2.

How do I get the difference of guids that do not exist in both.

I am certain that lsCheckedUsers has Guids that are in userids

Comment: `!lsCheckedUsers.Contains(lsCheckedUsers)` is note very interesting statement - will be constant (`false` I think) all the time...

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `IEnumerable<dynamic>` instead of `IEnumerable<Guid>`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**This is correct:**

`var userdifference = userids.Except(lsCheckedUsers);`

It will work if both of your `IEnumerable<dynamic>` actually contain `Guids`. Print out or inspect the items in each to make sure they are `Guids`.

You should really be using `IEnumerable<Guid>` and cast the incoming items to `Guids` if this is what you are expecting. It will hopefully prevent errors like the one you are potentially seeing.

Comment: When using dynamic objects the comparison wasn't working as should. I changed the types to actual Guid and that worked

Comment: @user1526912: Hmmm, interesting. It should definitely work as `dynamic` if the internal types are in fact `Guids`. I tested it with `IEnumerable<dynamic>` and `IEnumerable<Guid>` (simple tests -- a couple of `List<dynamic>` with some matching and non-matching `Guids` added). I wonder if your casting them to `Guids` did some sort of internal conversion...

Comment: Given *userIds* is empty and *lsCheckedUsers* has one record
when `userids.Except(lsCheckedUsers)`
used
then result will be empty

but when we call 
`lsCheckedUsers.Except(userids)`
then we will get one record from *lsCheckedUsers*

this may lead to confusion

Answer (score 2):

Something along those lines..

```
var difference = list1.Where (e => !list2.Any(a => a == e))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have:

```
var userdifference = userids.Where(i => !lsCheckedUsers.Contains(lsCheckedUsers));
```

But I think you mean:

```
var userdifference = userids.Where(i => !lsCheckedUsers.Contains(i));
```

**Update:**

To everyone marking down these answers because of "reference" comparisons, consider that Guid is a value type so its equality is evaluated differently. Try this simple test to convince yourself:

```
var guid = Guid.NewGuid();
var guids = new[] { new Guid(guid.ToString()) };

Console.WriteLine(guids.Contains(guid));
```

You'll see that the result is True.

Comment: It will work only if they are the same reference. Both lists are populated from database.

Comment: @VitorCanova That would normally be true, but Guid is a struct and its equality is evaluated in a different manner. Try it for yourself and see.

Comment: Sorry. Didn´t notice that. Why are you using dynamic?

Comment: Just checked (in the code) what [Guid](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/asw89aw8.aspx) does. It has an implementation of "Equal" that compares every segment.

Answer (score 1):

Enumerable has an Except method

[Enumerable.Except Method (IEnumerable, IEnumerable)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

And use String or GUID.
It will compare values for equals.

HashSet ExceptWith would probably have better performance.
But cannot use HashSet if you need to allow duplicates.

[HashSet.ExceptWith Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb299875.aspx)